# How to compare the DB.fetch hash output in Sequel ORM with an existing array?

Tags: ruby, sequel

How to compare the hash output of DB.fetch with an input array?

e.g. if on dataset from hash output of DB.fetch,
`dataset.each{|r| p r.values}` outputs arrays for each row but what if I want to store these arrays and compare these arrays and and also run computations outside of the `{}` scope with an existing array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataset.each{|r| p r.values}` returns not array, it prints them.

To get an array with array you could use:

```
DB[:yourtab].all.map{|v|v.values}
```

A more complete example:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:tab1){
  primary_key :id
  field :a, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
  field :b, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
}

DB[:tab1].insert(:a => 'a1', :b => 'b1')
DB[:tab1].insert(:a => 'a2', :b => 'b2')
DB[:tab1].insert(:a => 'a3', :b => 'b3')

result = DB[:tab1].all.map{|v|v.values}
p result
```

Result is:

```
[[1, "a1", "b1"], [2, "a2", "b2"], [3, "a3", "b3"]]
```

Comment: I know p is an alias for puts, I know it prints. Thanks.

Comment: `p`is no alias for `puts`. `puts`prints `Object#to_s` (or `Object#.to_str`). `p` prints `Object#inspect`. The result may be the same, but often it is a different output.